# By given name of a Git remote-tracking branch how to find which local branch tracks it?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

By a given name of a Git remote-tracking branch, for example, `upstream/develop` how to find which local branch tracks it if any?

If possible I'm looking for a solution that not relies on shell scripting and also works on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative is to use a [conditional format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-if) with `for-each-ref`

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=upstream/develop)%(upstream:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" refs/heads | sort -u
```

which could be more conveniently put into an alias like

```
git config --global alias.who-tracks '!f() { git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=upstream/$1)%(upstream:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" refs/heads | sort -u; }; f'

# then when you need it :
git who-tracks develop
git who-tracks another/branch
```

In this alias, I assumed a unique remote, but of course if you want to be able to use it on different remotes, tweak a little bit to include the remote name in the parameter :

```
git config --global alias.who-tracks '!f() { git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=$1)%(upstream:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" refs/heads | sort -u; }; f'

# then when you need it :
git who-tracks upstream/develop
git who-tracks origin/another/branch
```

Comment: I don't think you really need the `sort -u` here, and dropping it would probably help out on Windows (not that I use Windows so I don't really know for sure :-) ).

Comment: @torek True, but when I tried it without, the blank lines where kinda inesthetic and cumbersome. I guess it's an option ^^

Answer (score 5):

*Another* alternative is to filter the [very verbose](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--vv) output of the simple `git branch` with `grep`

```
git branch -vv | grep upstream/develop
```

Comment: My use case was to find the remote and branch that an independent upstream had used for their copy of my branch, based on a partial name for that branch ("po/glos..").  The `git branch -rl | grep po/glos` command was the generic solution to find it, based on your example!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](/a/3847586/5958455) (branch enumeration) and [this answer](/a/9753364/5958455) (retrieving upstream branch), you can iterate through local branches and check if any of them has the desired tracking remote branch:

```sh
git for-each-ref --shell \
  --format='test %(upstream:short) = "upstream/develop" && echo %(refname:short)' \
  refs/heads/ | sh
```

Comment: Why `--shell` and `| sh`?

Comment: @RomainValeri From [the man page}(https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---shell), `--shell` only makes substitution (`%(whatever)`) properly shell-quoted for direct evaluation, but does not call a shell by itself. The same holds for `--perl`, `--python` and `--tcl`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's clearer to me now ^^ Never used the option before